# how to make interactive form PDF using iText?

Tags: java, itext

Can any one please tell how to develop an application PDF form contains text box, checkbox and radio button. We have requirement in that pdf having different form fields to develop using iText java API?

Answer (score 3):

> Can any one please tell how to develop an application PDF form contains text box,

Cf. the samples by the original author of iText...

[Keyword TEXT FIELDS](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=254) e.g. [TextFields.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=157)

```
    TextField text = new TextField(writer, rectangle,
            String.format("text_%s", tf));
    text.setBackgroundColor(new GrayColor(0.75f));
    switch(tf) {
    case 1:
        text.setBorderStyle(PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_BEVELED);
        text.setText("Enter your name here...");
        text.setFontSize(0);
        text.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        text.setOptions(TextField.REQUIRED);
        break;
    case ...:
        ...
    }
    try {
        PdfFormField field = text.getTextField();
        ...
        writer.addAnnotation(field);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(ioe);
    }
    catch(DocumentException de) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
    }
```

> checkbox and

[Keyword BUTTON FIELDS > CHECKBOX](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=255), e.g. [Buttons.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=154)

```
    RadioCheckField checkbox;
    for (int i = 0; i < LANGUAGES.length; i++) {
        rect = new Rectangle(180, 806 - i * 40, 200, 788 - i * 40);
        checkbox = new RadioCheckField(writer, rect, LANGUAGES[i], "Yes");
        field = checkbox.getCheckField();
        field.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "Off", onOff[0]);
        field.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "Yes", onOff[1]);
        writer.addAnnotation(field);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
            new Phrase(LANGUAGES[i], font), 210, 790 - i * 40, 0);
    }
```

> radio button.

[Keyword BUTTON FIELDS > RADIO FIELD](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=256), e.g. [RadioButtons.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=155)

```
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    // create a radio field spanning different pages
    PdfFormField radiogroup = PdfFormField.createRadioButton(writer, true);
    radiogroup.setFieldName("language");
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(40, 806, 60, 788);
    RadioCheckField radio;
    PdfFormField radiofield;
    for (int page = 0; page < LANGUAGES.length; ) {
        radio = new RadioCheckField(writer, rect, null, LANGUAGES[page]);
        radio.setBackgroundColor(new GrayColor(0.8f));
        radiofield = radio.getRadioField();
        radiofield.setPlaceInPage(++page);
        radiogroup.addKid(radiofield);
    }
    writer.addAnnotation(radiogroup);
```

Of course, please have a look at the complete source of the sample to put it into context. If possible, read the book [ITEXT IN ACTION — SECOND EDITION](http://itextpdf.com/book/) to understand what you are doing.